# How to keep gridview (or ListView) item selected and not lose the selection because of recycling

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I have constantly run into the problem of having my selected items in a listView (currently a gridview) stay selected. I am using the BaseAdapter. I have a general idea of how the holder pattern works but I'm not too sure on how I should save the state of each specific view. That is the state of whether it is clicked or not. Should I create another class to act as a model or should I use getTag and setTag?
Thanks for the help.
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to not worry about saving the view's state. Instead, save/change the state of underlying data. So if a position is selected, place the position in a data structure (usually a SparseBooleanArray). When this position comes back into view, i.e. getView() is called for this position, update the view properties accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll give that a shot now. Also I'm changing the color of the background by calling view.setBackgroundColor, is ok to use?

Comment: @LonelyVagrant Sure. But do reset the background color. Example if (selected) {view.setBackgroundColor(selectedColor);} else {view.setBackgroundColor(normalColor);}. The else statement is important here. Other wise, it will look like some items are selected even though they aren't

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. That actually might have been my problem in the past. Cheers

Comment: Thanks a bunch mate, I managed to get it to work.Although I lost some functionality because I need access to the SparseBooleanArray in the class that calls the adapter class. What would be the proper way of sending the SparseBooleanArray from the adapter to it's calling class? I have the context so should I just use a cast and call a method from the calling class? So for example   ((ClassThatCallsAdapter)context).getSparseBooleanArray(); ?    Again, thanks for all the help with these beginner questions.

Comment: @LonelyVagrant I would rather use an interface that opens a communication channel between the activity and the adapter. BUT, the usual implementation is as follows: I am assuming that you have an implementation of `MultiChoiceModeListener` in your activity. Then, the SparseBooleanArray should be a member of your adapter. When something is checked/unchecked, you call `mAdapter.setPositionToChecked(position)` . You will need to add this method to your adapter to toggle selection status of that position.

Comment: @LonelyVagrant In this case, you don't need a method like `getSparseBooleanArray()` in your activity. All operations on the SparseBooleanArray happen on the adapter side and the activity does not need to know of these changes.